# Calling a python function using make

Tags: python, makefile

I have a Python script named `sample.py` containing multiple functions.

```
def A():
    return 3

def B():
    return [i for i in range(2,10)]
```

I have to write a `Makefile` which calls the function B from `sample.py` and stores its output to another file (say `output.txt`); i.e. I wish to run `make output.txt` from the command line and store the result of calling function B from `sample.py`. How do I write the recipe for it?
We can call a script directly from the `Makefile`, but how do I call a particular function?

```
output.txt:sample.py
    ___recipe___
```

Comment: can you not just put the B function in its own file and run that?

Comment: No, in the current scenario, I can't. I already figured out calling a function from the MAKEFILE, but that's not what I want. What if there are multiple functions?It wouldn't be too wise, to create a separate file for each of them.

Comment: `make` *can't* call just a Python function; it can only run a command that can execute a Python script that calls the function.

Answer (score 3):

`python -c <cmd>` allows you to pass a string of Python code to the interpreter. So we just need to write a one-liner script (semicolons *do* work in Python; they just normally aren't necessary and are discouraged) that imports the `.py` file and calls the function. Something like:

```
output.txt: sample.py
    python -c "import sample; print(sample.B())" > output.txt
```

Comment: Printing a list will print its Python representation (so in this case, `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` plus newline) which might not be exactly what the OP had in mind. It's not really clear what they mean by "output" anyway.